# Constants are undefined while testing using Enzyme + React Native + Jest

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, constants, jestjs, enzyme

I want to unit test my React Native component with Enzyme and Jest.

It is a QR Scanner that calls a function after a successful scan. This function communicates with the server and returns a response. It then uses a `switch` statement to determine what to do next. When I just use the app, the component and it's function works finde. But the unit tests for this function fail, because all constants are undefined. How can I fix this?

For reference, here is the code of my unit tests (stripped for clarity):

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { Alert, View } from "react-native";

import * as qrCodeFunctions from "../../api/qrCodes/qrCodes";
import { ScannerScreen } from "./ScannerScreen";

Alert.alert = jest.fn();

const createTestProps = props => ({
  navigation: { navigate: jest.fn() },
  setData: jest.fn(),
  ...props
});

describe("ScannerScreen", () => {
  describe("rendering", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let props;
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps();
      wrapper = shallow(<ScannerScreen {...props} />);
    });

    it("should render a <View />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(View)).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    it("should render a <QRCodeScanner />", () => {
      expect(wrapper.find("QRCodeScanner")).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });

  describe("interaction", () => {
    let wrapper;
    let props;
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = createTestProps();
      wrapper = shallow(<ScannerScreen {...props} />);
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    describe("scanning the qr code", () => {
      describe("data received", () => {
        qrCodeFunctions.executeQRCodeFunction = jest.fn(
          () =>
            new Promise(resolve =>
              resolve({
                entities: {
                  houses: {
                    "b813d3d1-9fdb-47bf-92ee-f7cb8bd6564b": {
                      category: "villa",
                      price: 2.400.000,
                      uuid: "b813d3d1-9fdb-47bf-92ee-f7cb8bd6564b"
                    }
                  },
                  ...
                },
                result: {
                  detail: "Successfully received villas.",
                  qrCodeData: "aeb1717f-480f-415f-9d15-00906750cae2"
                }
              })
            )
        );
        it("should dispatch an event to set the data and show an alert", () => {
          wrapper.instance().onRead({ data: { v1QRCodeData: "abc" } });
          expect(qrCodeFunctions.executeQRCodeFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
          expect(props.setData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
          expect(Alert.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

`props.setData` should be (and is called while not unit testing) called depending on a switch statement just like this:

```
  onRead = e => {
    executeQRCodeFunction(e.data.v1QRCodeData)
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.result);
        console.log(SERVER_VALUES_QR_CODE_DETAIL_VILLAS_RECEIVED);
        console.log(data.result.detail);
        console.log(data.result.detail == SERVER_VALUES_QR_CODE_DETAIL_VILLAS_RECEIVED);
        switch (data.result.detail) {
          case SERVER_VALUES_QR_CODE_DETAIL_VILLAS_RECEIVED:
            this.villasReceived(data);
            break;
          ...
          default:
            alert(data.result);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };
```

The function `villasReceived` then calls setData. But in the unit tests this never happens, because the switch case always refers to the default case. Furthermore the results of the console logs are, that `data.result` and `data.result.detail` are correct, but the comparison is `false` and the constant `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem; my Jest test was failing with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined` at this line in one of my modules:

```
import { Constants } from 'expo';

...

  const storeVersion = Constants.manifest.version;    // test fails here

...
```

## Solution

You can follow [mock a node module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) in the Jest docs.

I created a file `\__mocks__\expo.js` (the `__mocks__` folder needs to be adjacent to the `node_modules` folder) with this in it:

```
const Constants = {
  manifest: {
    version: '1.0.0',
  },
};

export {
  Constants
};
```

Obviously you'd construct the dummy Constants object containing whatever properties you needed.